# How can I check if the user already rated the item in NodeJS & Mongoose Application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following schemas in Mongoose:

```
UserSchema = new Schema({
    ratings = [{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Rating'}] })

ItemSchema = new Schema({
    ratings = [{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Rating'}] })

Rating = new Schema({
    user = [{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'User'}],
    venue = [{type : Schema.ObjectId, ref : 'Venue'}]
})
```

Are they right? I should query ratings by users, ratings for items. Also I want to check if the user has already rated an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two of the following options you can go with.

You can maintain a separate collection `Rating` quite similar to what you would have done in SQL.

```
User: voter (reference to User object),
Item: item_voted (reference to item object),
Rating: what so ever user rated
Time: time_rated,
other fields as per your requirements...
```

Now maintain index over `User` and `Item` to boost up queries to check if user already rated for an item or not.

`OR` you could maintain an array in `User` collection for items rated by that user, and index over that array. Here it is what you can have your data model for `User` like.

```
items_rated: [item1, item2, item3]
other fields of User as per your requirements...
```

This second approach has a limitation that it fails if your BSON records exceeds 16MB limit, but in practical usage it very very less probable that you actually would hit that limit. Though nothing can be said. If your Users turn out to be maniac like some top stackoverflow users you will hit that 16MB wall :P

The way you can check if item has been rated or not (if you opt for second choice is)

```
if (db.user.count({item_rated: item_k, _id:'user-id-1'}) == 0) { ... }
```